# Using sa-learn on already filtered mails?

Tags: spam-prevention, spamassassin

To have spamassasin working correctly you need to train it: feeding it ham and spam messages.

But what happens when you feed it spam messages which have already been processed?

And by that I mean: they've got a [SPAM] text in their subject, it contains the analysis detail of why it's considered as spam, and the actual spam message is sent as an attachment.

Does sa-learn know how to handle that, or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run `sa-learn` on messages that SA has already marked as spam, it will learn from them whatever you told it (`--spam` or `--ham`), but first, it will *remove* the SA headers that were initially added to the message.

This is needed because you want to be able to train SA to consider something hammy that it's already marked as spam, in case of false positives, and vice-versa.

Note that sa-learn places its *own* marking on messages that it learns from, and will not learn from them again unless you explicitly tell it to `--forget` messages. However, if you tell it to learn something as spammy that you previously learned as hammy, or vice versa (e.g. you misfiled it), it will figure this out and automatically forget the previous run.